# NullReferenceException using AutoMapper and StructureMap

Tags: c#, exception, inversion-of-control, structuremap, automapper

So, I get a NullReferenceException thrown on a production server. It's not reproducible and happens once every ~100 request.

This is the code.

```
var userInfo = Mapper.Map<UserSubscribedEvent, UserInfo>(userSubscribedEvent);
var subscription = repository.GetActiveSubscriptionForUser(userInfo.UserId);
```

The exception appears on the second line. So it's either userInfo that is null or it is the repository.

The repository is injected into the class from the constructor using StructureMap so it really should not be null (since it usually works) and userInfo is created using AutoMapper and should not be null either.

So my question is - Can Mapper.Map return null in AutoMapper, if so, when? 
If not, have anyone experienced that StructureMap randomly injects null dependencies into the constructor? 
If so, can it be avoided?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not add a check between those two lines? That way you'll be able to work out which one it is, and concentrate your investigations on that one problem... Is `userSubscribedEvent` definitely non-null, btw? I haven't used AutoMapper (or StructureMap) but is it possible that Mapper.Map can return null if the input value is null?

Comment: Are you certain that the exception is not thrown inside the `GetActiveSubscriptionForUser` method?

Comment: Put a try-catch around and add some logging in the catch clause.

Comment: My goal was to avoid deploying a new version with additional logging. If that cannot be avoided I'll default back to that. It is correct that AutoMapper will return null if the parameter is null. The parameter in question comes directly from JSON that I have logged as not null, so it should not be the problem, even if I cant rule it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was actually on the line below when used a property on subscription (embarrassed), the server ran with a file that had an extra empty line at the top. There where no active subscriptions since the client sent in the request just after it had closed the active subscription. :-/

Thanks again for your help and sorry for not checking my own production code better.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Mapper.Map return null in AutoMapper

Yes.

> if so, when?

If you pass null as argument. In your case this would be the `userSubscribedEvent` variable.